# Change background color of colorbar when using transparent colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

Context: Matplotlib scatter plots.
When using transparency (`alpha`<1) in scatter plots and an axis background color other than white, the colors in the corresponding colorbar look different. This is clearly visible in the figure below: The colorbar on the right looks "too bright". However, setting the background color of the axis of the colorbar does not change this.

So the **question**: How can I change the background color of colorbar with transparent colors?

I'm using Python 2.7.3 and Matplotlib 1.3.1 (on Ubuntu 12.04)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(10) #for reproducability

n = 10
ticks = range(n)
data = np.hstack((np.random.rand(50,2),np.random.randint(0,n,(50,1))))
colors = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet',n)(ticks)
lcmap = plt.matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax = plt.subplot(121)
plt.scatter(data[:,0],data[:,1], c=data[:,2], s=40, alpha=0.3, 
        edgecolor='none', cmap=lcmap)
plt.colorbar(ticks=ticks)
plt.clim(-0.5,9.5)

ax = plt.subplot(122)
plt.scatter(data[:,0],data[:,1], c=data[:,2], s=40, alpha=0.3, 
        edgecolor='none', cmap=lcmap)
cb = plt.colorbar(ticks=ticks)
ax.set_axis_bgcolor((0.2,0.2,0.2))
cb.ax.set_axis_bgcolor((0.2,0.2,0.2))
plt.clim(-0.5,9.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this line *after* your `plt.clim` call,

```
cb.patch.set_facecolor((0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0))
```

Comment: awesome, that does the trick. I'm not quite sure why, though.

Comment: Honestly I don't really know why either. Apparently they use this patch for the colorbar background rather than the standard axisbg.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. Interestingly, making the patch fully transparent (`cb.patch.set_alpha(0)`), does not change anything...

Comment: Ya, I noticed that too. Presumably @tcaswell would know the answer.