# Wrong background color when using colorbar "extend" and ggplot in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ggplot2, colorbar

I'm using matplotlib to plot some spatial data, but I'm getting a minor graphical error when I use the "extend" feature of the colorbar together with the "ggplot" style: the background color behind the pointed ends of the colorbar are gray when they should be white.  You can see what I mean here:

[image: example of colorbar problem]

Here's the code I used to make this example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make some random data
random_data = np.random.randint(-10,10,size=(10,10))

# Plot a figure
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
plt.contourf(random_data,np.arange(-5,5,1),extend='both')
plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

I think this issue started a few months ago when I updated Spyder (and probably some other packages).  I don't see other examples of this issue online.  If I don't use the "ggplot" style, the background is the right color.

Any idea what the problem is?  I'm using python 3.7.11.  Here are all of my python packages:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       1_gnu
affine                    2.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0
appdirs                   1.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
argcomplete               1.12.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
argh                      0.26.2                   py37_0
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py37h27cfd23_1
astroid                   2.5              py37h06a4308_1
async_generator           1.10             py37h28b3542_0
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0
attrs                     21.2.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
autopep8                  1.5.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
aws-c-common              0.4.57               he6710b0_1
aws-c-event-stream        0.1.6                h2531618_5
aws-checksums             0.1.9                he6710b0_0
aws-sdk-cpp               1.8.185              hce553d0_0
babel                     2.9.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
bagit                     1.7.0                      py_0    conda-forge
black                     19.10b0                    py_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    4.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
bokeh                     2.3.3            py37h06a4308_0
bottleneck                1.3.2            py37heb32a55_1
brotli                    1.0.9                he6710b0_2
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py37h27cfd23_1003
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0
c-ares                    1.17.1               h27cfd23_0
ca-certificates           2021.10.8            ha878542_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.16.0               hf32fb01_1
cartopy                   0.18.0           py37h0d9ca2b_1
certifi                   2021.10.8        py37h89c1867_1    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.6           py37h400218f_0
cfitsio                   3.470                hf0d0db6_6
cftime                    1.5.0            py37h6323ea4_0
chardet                   4.0.0           py37h06a4308_1003
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
click                     7.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
click-plugins             1.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
cligj                     0.7.2            py37h06a4308_0
cloudpickle               2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
colorcet                  2.0.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0
contextily                1.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cryptography              3.4.8            py37hd23ed53_0
curl                      7.78.0               h1ccaba5_0
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0
cytoolz                   0.11.0           py37h7b6447c_0
dask                      2021.8.1           pyhd3eb1b0_0
dask-core                 2021.8.1           pyhd3eb1b0_0
datashader                0.13.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
datashape                 0.5.4            py37h06a4308_1
dbus                      1.13.18              hb2f20db_0
debugpy                   1.4.1            py37h295c915_0
decorator                 5.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
demjson                   2.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
diff-match-patch          20200713           pyhd3eb1b0_0
dill                      0.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
distributed               2021.8.1         py37h06a4308_0
docutils                  0.17.1           py37h06a4308_1
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0
eofs                      1.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
et_xmlfile                1.1.0            py37h06a4308_0
expat                     2.4.1                h2531618_2
fastdtw                   0.2.0                      py_1    bioconda
fiona                     1.8.13.post1     py37hc820daa_0
flake8                    3.8.4                      py_0
fontconfig                2.13.1               h6c09931_0
fonttools                 4.25.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
freetype                  2.10.4               h5ab3b9f_0
freexl                    1.0.6                h27cfd23_0
fsspec                    2021.8.1           pyhd3eb1b0_0
future                    0.18.2                   py37_1
gdal                      3.0.2            py37h4694593_1
geographiclib             1.52               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
geopandas                 0.9.0                      py_1
geopandas-base            0.9.0                      py_1
geoplot                   0.4.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
geopy                     2.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
geos                      3.8.0                he6710b0_0
geotiff                   1.6.0                h21e8280_0
geoviews                  1.9.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
geoviews-core             1.9.1              pyh06a4308_0
giflib                    5.2.1                h7b6447c_0
glib                      2.69.1               h5202010_0
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               h8213a91_2
gstreamer                 1.14.0               h28cd5cc_2
hdf4                      4.2.13               h3ca952b_2
hdf5                      1.10.6               hb1b8bf9_0
heapdict                  1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
holoviews                 1.14.6             pyhd3eb1b0_1
icu                       58.2                 he6710b0_3
idna                      3.2                pyhd3eb1b0_0
imagesize                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
importlib-metadata        4.8.1            py37h06a4308_0
importlib_metadata        4.8.1                hd3eb1b0_0
iniconfig                 1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2021.3.0          h06a4308_3350
intervaltree              3.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
ipykernel                 6.4.1            py37h06a4308_1
ipython                   7.27.0           py37hb070fc8_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
isort                     5.9.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jedi                      0.17.2           py37h06a4308_1
jeepney                   0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jinja2                    3.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
joblib                    1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jpeg                      9d                   h7f8727e_0
json-c                    0.13.1               h1bed415_0
jsonschema                3.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
jupyter_client            7.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_core              4.8.1            py37h06a4308_0
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
kealib                    1.4.14               h54c064f_0
keyring                   23.1.0           py37h06a4308_0
kiwisolver                1.3.1            py37h2531618_0
krb5                      1.19.2               hac12032_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.6.0            py37h27cfd23_0
lcms2                     2.12                 h3be6417_0
ld_impl_linux-64          2.35.1               h7274673_9
libboost                  1.73.0              h3ff78a5_11
libcurl                   7.78.0               h0b77cf5_0
libdap4                   3.19.1               h6ec2957_0
libedit                   3.1.20210714         h7f8727e_0
libev                     4.33                 h7f8727e_1
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2
libgcc-ng                 9.3.0               h5101ec6_17
libgdal                   3.0.2                h7c14f60_1
libgfortran-ng            7.5.0               ha8ba4b0_17
libgfortran4              7.5.0               ha8ba4b0_17
libgomp                   9.3.0               h5101ec6_17
libkml                    1.3.0                h7ecb851_5
libllvm10                 10.0.1               hbcb73fb_5
libnetcdf                 4.6.1                h2053bdc_4
libnghttp2                1.41.0               hf8bcb03_2
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0
libpq                     12.2                 h553bfba_1
libsodium                 1.0.18               h7b6447c_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h2531618_0
libspatialite             4.3.0a               h793db0d_0
libssh2                   1.9.0                h1ba5d50_1
libstdcxx-ng              9.3.0               hd4cf53a_17
libtiff                   4.2.0                h85742a9_0
libuuid                   1.0.3                h7f8727e_2
libwebp-base              1.2.0                h27cfd23_0
libxcb                    1.14                 h7b6447c_0
libxml2                   2.9.12               h03d6c58_0
lipd                      0.2.8.6                  pypi_0    pypi
llvmlite                  0.36.0           py37h612dafd_4
locket                    0.2.1            py37h06a4308_1
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h295c915_1
mapclassify               2.4.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
markdown                  3.3.4            py37h06a4308_0
markupsafe                2.0.1            py37h27cfd23_0
matplotlib                3.4.2            py37h06a4308_0
matplotlib-base           3.4.2            py37hab158f2_0
matplotlib-inline         0.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_2
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
mercantile                1.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py37h14c3975_1001
mkl                       2021.3.0           h06a4308_520
mkl-service               2.4.0            py37h7f8727e_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.0            py37h42c9631_2
mkl_random                1.2.2            py37h51133e4_0
msgpack-python            1.0.2            py37hff7bd54_1
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0
multiprocess              0.70.11.1                pypi_0    pypi
munch                     2.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0
mypy_extensions           0.4.3                    py37_0
nbclient                  0.5.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nbconvert                 6.1.0            py37h06a4308_0
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nc-time-axis              1.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.2                  he6710b0_1
nest-asyncio              1.5.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
netcdf4                   1.5.7            py37h0a24e14_0
networkx                  2.6.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
notebook                  6.4.3            py37h06a4308_0
numba                     0.53.1           py37ha9443f7_0
numexpr                   2.7.3            py37h22e1b3c_1
numpy                     1.20.3           py37hf144106_0
numpy-base                1.20.3           py37h74d4b33_0
numpydoc                  1.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h3ad879b_0
openpyxl                  3.0.9              pyhd3eb1b0_0
openssl                   1.1.1l               h7f8727e_0
packaging                 21.0               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pandas                    1.3.3            py37h8c16a72_0
pandocfilters             1.4.3            py37h06a4308_1
panel                     0.12.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
param                     1.11.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
parso                     0.7.0                      py_0
partd                     1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pathos                    0.2.7                    pypi_0    pypi
pathspec                  0.7.0                      py_0
patsy                     0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pcre                      8.45                 h295c915_0
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    8.3.1            py37h2c7a002_0
pip                       21.0.1           py37h06a4308_0
pixman                    0.40.0               h7f8727e_1
pluggy                    1.0.0            py37h06a4308_0
pooch                     1.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
poppler                   0.81.0               h01f5e8b_2
poppler-data              0.4.10               h06a4308_0
postgresql                12.2                 h553bfba_1
pox                       0.2.9                    pypi_0    pypi
ppft                      1.6.6.3                  pypi_0    pypi
proj                      6.2.1                haa6030c_0
prometheus_client         0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.20             pyhd3eb1b0_0
psutil                    5.8.0            py37h27cfd23_1
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
py                        1.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pycodestyle               2.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2
pyct                      0.4.8                    py37_0
pydocstyle                6.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyflakes                  2.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pygeos                    0.6              py37hb106bac_1    conda-forge
pygments                  2.10.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyleoclim                 0.4.10                   pypi_0    pypi
pylint                    2.7.4            py37h06a4308_1
pyls-black                0.4.6                hd3eb1b0_0
pyls-spyder               0.3.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyopengl                  3.1.1a1          py37h06a4308_0
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd3eb1b0_1
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyproj                    2.6.1.post1      py37hb3025e9_1
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h05f1152_2
pyrsistent                0.17.3           py37h7b6447c_0
pyshp                     2.1.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_1
pytest                    6.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.7.11               h12debd9_0
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-jsonrpc-server     0.4.0                      py_0
python-language-server    0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
python_abi                3.7                     2_cp37m    conda-forge
pytz                      2021.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyviz_comms               2.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyxdg                     0.27               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyyaml                    5.4.1            py37h27cfd23_1
pyzmq                     22.2.1           py37h295c915_1
qdarkstyle                2.8.1                      py_0
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1
qtawesome                 1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtconsole                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtpy                      1.10.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
rasterio                  1.1.0            py37h41e4f33_0
readline                  8.1                  h27cfd23_0
regex                     2021.8.3         py37h7f8727e_0
regionmask                0.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.26.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
rope                      0.19.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
rpy2                      3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
rtree                     0.9.7            py37h06a4308_1
scikit-learn              0.24.2           py37ha9443f7_0
scipy                     1.7.1            py37h292c36d_2
seaborn                   0.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
seaborn-base              0.11.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
secretstorage             3.3.1            py37h06a4308_0
send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
setuptools                58.0.4           py37h06a4308_0
shapely                   1.7.1            py37h1728cc4_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sip                       6.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
snowballstemmer           2.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
snuggs                    1.4.7              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sortedcontainers          2.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinx                    4.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
spyder                    4.2.5            py37h06a4308_0
spyder-kernels            1.10.2           py37h06a4308_0
sqlite                    3.36.0               hc218d9a_0
statsmodels               0.12.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tbb                       2020.3               hfd86e86_0
tblib                     1.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
terminado                 0.9.4            py37h06a4308_0
testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
textdistance              4.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
threadpoolctl             2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
three-merge               0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tiledb                    2.2.9                hffe1d7a_0
tk                        8.6.11               h1ccaba5_0
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
toolz                     0.11.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
tornado                   6.1              py37h27cfd23_0
tqdm                      4.60.0                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
typed-ast                 1.4.3            py37h7f8727e_1
typing_extensions         3.10.0.2           pyh06a4308_0
tzlocal                   2.1                      pypi_0    pypi
ujson                     4.0.2            py37h2531618_0
urllib3                   1.26.7             pyhd3eb1b0_0
watchdog                  1.0.2            py37h06a4308_1
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
wheel                     0.37.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
windrose                  1.6.8              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.12.1           py37h7b6447c_1
wurlitzer                 2.1.1            py37h06a4308_0
xarray                    0.16.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
xerces-c                  3.2.3                h780794e_0
xlrd                      2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
xz                        5.2.5                h7b6447c_0
yaml                      0.2.5                h7b6447c_0
yapf                      0.31.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
zeromq                    4.3.4                h2531618_0
zict                      2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
zipp                      3.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3
zstd                      1.4.9                haebb681_0
```

Comment: You can work arround the problem with `cbar = plt.colorbar(...); cbar.ax.set_facecolor('none')`

Comment: A related question:  [Matplotlib: change background color of colorbar (when using transparent colors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851194/matplotlib-change-background-color-of-colorbar-when-using-transparent-colors)

Comment: Thanks JohanC!  Your workaround did the trick!

Comment: This should also not be a problem in 3.5 (though we broke some things as well, that will hopefully be fixed in 3.5.1)